# Updating a google calendar event as an attendee

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to modify an event that has `guestsCanModify` set to true from an attendee's calendar. If I update the event in the user's primary calendar, in google calendar I see `You have made changes to details of this event that will only be reflected on this calendar` and event in the original calendar is not updated. If I try to update the event in the original calendar, I get 404. If I make the changes manually through google calendar UI as that user, the changes are propagated to the original calendar.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a moment to read our [ask] page and get some hints on how to improve this questions.  Good questions attract better, faster answers